# How to get machinename from servers SSL certificate

Tags: c#, ssl

I have an embedded system that runs a SSL server. I created the server certificate using openSSL. I have also created a SSL client in C# running on my Windows machine. How can I get the machine name of my server so that the I can create SSL connection to that server.

Answer (score 0):

there are different names for your machine.
try `hostname` `/etc/hosts`  `ping <ip>`